# rails query interface joins argument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to make use of Active Record Query Interface joins

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/active_record_querying.html#using-arrayhash-of-named-associations

I have the associations for the two models working correctly, but when I try to run this query...

```
Package.all :joins => :drugs
```

I receive the:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Rails are you running? The documentation is pretty old (v2.3) and a lot has changed since then.

Try using `Package.joins(:drugs).all` instead.

Comment: this is exactly what i needed, thanks. I will accept the answer in few minutes when the time has cleared,